# :vimgrep and the quickfix window in MacVim

Tags: vim, grep, macvim

I'm converting from Textmate to MacVim and I'm struggling with replicating Textmate's 'Find in Project' feature. I can search just fine with `:vimgrep /foo/g **/*.py` and open the quickfix window with `:cope`. From there I can navigate to and open the appropriate match without issue.

My problem is that if the match I opened isn't the correct one, I can't find a way of bringing back the search results window without running the entire search again. I can open the quickfox window with `:cope` again but it only contains 1 result, the file I just opened.

What is the general workflow for searching multiple files and managing the results?

Comment: My preference is to grep in a separate shell.

Comment: The quickfix window should be usable even after you jumped to one of the files. In fact, I couldn't find a way to clear the buffer without restarting the search.

Comment: @nimrodm Interesting. I'm actually using the latest MacVim but I tried this with the Snow Leopard's Terminal Vim and you're right, it works. In MacVim the quickfix list window gets cleared when I open a file. I've edited the question to say I'm using MacVim.

Comment: @Tim: I'm using MacVim 7.3 here (Aug 15, 2010 release) and it seems to work find in terminal and using the gui version. Perhaps there's something in your vimrc file messing things up? How about removing it and trying again.

Comment: @nimrodm You're spot on! For some reason having `filetype plugin indent on` in my `.vimrc` file causes this to break. I'll dig further to find out what's going on but that's definitely it. Thanks!

Comment: When you do have to work with Textmate, take a look at the Ackmate plugin.  https://github.com/protocool/AckMate/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the issue was that a Vim script/plugin was somehow interfering with the normal operation of the quickfix window. I've realised that when dealing with Vim issues like this it's good practice to strip Vim back to the bare essentials and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with quickfix, and after noticing your comment about `filetype plugin indent on` causing the quickfix window to clear immediately, tracked this to a plugin: jslint, which was setting the quickfix window every time a javascript file was opened or written to. You might have had a similar plugin enabled for some open filetype.

Comment: I use Syntastic which can be made to use the location list instead of the quickfix list: `let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1`

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually use vimgrep, I use one of two plugins:
[Ack](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) or [grep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311). Maybe you have better luck using one of these two.

Answer (score 3):

You can move through the quickfix list with `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. I find the mappings from [unimpaired](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) very useful so `]q` for `:cnext` and `[q` for `:cprevious`.
If you want just the mappings and not the whole unimpaired plugin put the following in your .vimrc file.

```
nnoremap ]q :cnext<cr>
nnoremap [q :cprevious<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works now. The original problem was that the list disappeared when I opened the first file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, You want to search for a particular string which can be in many files in your project and then do some modification with that string, then return back to original window and (if required), do the same process again?

If that's not the case, ignore my post else use cscope.

1. Build the cscope Data base using:
   `cscope -Rb` in your project root directory. This will create `cscope.out` file
2. open vim and add the cscope database using:

   :cs add
3. find the string as:

   :cs f s
4. Go to file of your wish from the command 3 result and do the required modifications.
5. Again use step 3, or press `ctrl + ^` to go back to your original file.

Comment: Thanks Vikram.exe. This is not quite what I want though. I just want to search all files for a string, get a list of matches and then persue those files through returning to the original result list.

Answer (score 0):

What dreel is suggesting is probably a fix.  I had the same issue with quickfix content disappearing and it turns out it was being caused by the pyflakes.vim linter.  The linter was trying to create quickfix entries for lint errors, but it just had the effect of clearing quickfix content from searches.  I set an option for the linter plugin that disabled quickfix support and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `:colder` and `:cnewer` commands can be used to navigate to previous/newer quickfix (error) lists.

From the vim help:

**:colder**

```
:col[der] [count]   Go to older error list.  When [count] is given, do
            this [count] times.  When already at the oldest error
            list, an error message is given.
```

**:cnewer**

```
:cnew[er] [count]   Go to newer error list.  When [count] is given, do
            this [count] times.  When already at the newest error
            list, an error message is given.
```